# Final expression in for loop does not increase global variable

Tags: for-loop

I am having trouble getting this code to work, its supposed to run just twice but when I check the console, it runs infinitely. Why is `a` not getting increased?

```
var a=1;
(function man() {
  console.log('foo');
  for (;a<3;a++){
     console.log(a);
     man();}
})();
```

If I rewrite the code thus, it runs just fine.

```
var a=1;
 (function man() {
   console.log('foo');
     for (;a<3;){
     a++;
     console.log(a);
     man();}
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first example the third part ( 'a' increment part) get executed only after the completion of an iteration which never happens because of the recursive call. Second example it gets incremented when the iteration starts

Comment: I thought since it got to the recursive call, that's the end of one iteration. I just noted that if there were other expressions after the recursive call, they won't be executed.